# applying the sigma function in R

Tags: r, math, quantitative-finance

I am trying to replicate a graph on an example on Danish Data set used in the text Non-Life Insurance Mathematics.

I want to create the following new variable from my data set so I can plot the graph. My biggest challenge is how to sum(sigma) over w over j given that I have to start from max of two values to min of two values. I don't have the faintest idea how to do it in R. Guess I have a lot to still learn in how to do operations in R.

I would appreciate if some how can give me useful tip on how to go about it.

Below is the equation in question I couldn't replace the sigma sign so I used the literally interpretation (sum)

```
1/λ(i)) = 1/(2m + 1) *  sum Wj from {j=max(1,i−m) to min(n,i+m)} for m = 50.
```

Comment: What is `Wj`? Is it a function or a collection/vector of values?

Comment: wj is the actually arrival time for 2000 plus observations

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
m = 50
total = 0
for (j in seq(max(1, i-m), min(n, i+m)) {
  total = total + W[j]
}
total = total / (2 * m + 1)
lambda = 1 / total
```

or this

```
m = 50
lambda = 1 / (sum(W[max(i,i-m) : min(n,i+m)]) / (2 * m + 1))
```

Comment: Don't we have any function to implement the `sigma` notation for summation of a series?

Comment: @MonaJalal There is the `sum` function.